# How to get performance metrics from Cypress.io and react.js

Tags: reactjs, puppeteer, cypress, lighthouse

I am using an app created in React.js. I used, lighthouse and puppeteer for performance testing. There I am getting performance metrics and code coverage both.

Now, the requirement is to do performance test with Cypress.io. I am able to perform unit tests for all files. But, when I am looking for code coverage I am getting response:

[image]

I used the following code for code coverage:
//plugins/index.js

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    // `on` is used to hook into various events Cypress emits
    // `config` is the resolved Cypress config
    on('task', require('@cypress/code-coverage/task'))
}
```

//support/index.js

```
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'
```

Requirement:

1. I am getting unit tests passed on cypress. But, not able to get anything on code coverage.
2. Generate performance metrics similar to lighthouse/puppeteer provides.

Please suggest anything which can help me in this situation. any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: how did you performance test in the end?